WordPress mmenu not working if on a sub page
I am using the WordPress Plugin on a new WP installation (WP 6.5.2) using a FSE Theme (Twenty Twenty-Three). All works fine, beautiful menu, just if I am on a small screen, on a sub-page and click the menu button, the panel opens but it is empty.
What shall I do to fix that?
Thanks and regards, Karin
What shall I do to fix that? It does not make a difference if the pages are "real" sub pages (sub pages that hierarchically have a main page) or if they are just fake sub pages (the have no main page)
Thanks and regards, Karin

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I found a solution:
On the option "Select how to navigate" I choose "With breadcrumbs" - Now I can use the menu on sub pages as well. :)
